# Add Unique values from one table to another

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

I am updating between two tables with something like:

```
Insert into TableA (Field1,Field2) 
Select Field3,Field4 from TableB 
where Field3 NOT IN (Select Field1 from TableA
```

What I failed to take into account is that this does not check for dupes from TableB so regardless of my NOT IN I still get duplicates added.

Comment: Do you mean duplicates that exist in TableB or rows already in TableA?

Answer (score 0):

Add `DISTINCT` in front of the values in your select. this will remove any duplicates

```
INSERT INTO TableA (Field1,Field2) 
SELECT DISTINCT Field3,Field4 
FROM TableB
WHERE Field3 NOT IN (Select Field1 from TableA)
```

This will not work if there are rows where 3 is the same but 4 is not in this case use `GROUP BY`

```
INSERT INTO TableA (Field1,Field2) 
SELECT Field3,Field4 
FROM TableB
WHERE Field3 NOT IN (Select Field1 from TableA)
GROUP BY Field3
```

Comment: Thanks, to clarify do you mean the first example works where FIeld3 is distinct and not Field3 AND Field4 or the second example? I'm only looking for cases where Field3 is distinct but still want to insert Field4.

Comment: the first example will work fine if there are no entrees where Field3 is the same but Field4 is not. example values: (3,5) and (3,6). Because DISTINCT checks for the whole thing they will both be added.

The second query will only add on of those rows. But it's up to you to to clarify which want you'd like it to use. maybe min or max value of Field4? or leave it like this and it will take a whichever row comes first or last (not entirely sure without checking).

What do you want to happen if there are multiple rows with same Field3 but different Field4?